# Variables optimized out with g++ and the -Og option

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-flags

When I compile my C++ program with `g++` using the `-Og` option I see variables that are `<optimized out>`, and also the current line sometimes skips around. Is this behaviour expected at this optimization level, or do I have some problem? The man page of gcc says:

> -Og 
> Optimize debugging experience.  `-Og` enables optimizations that do not interfere with debugging. It should be the optimization level of choice for the standard edit-compile-debug cycle, offering a reasonable level of optimization while maintaining fast compilation and a good debugging experience.

hence I did not expect this behaviour. On my system I have g++ version 4.9.2 and gdb version 7.7.1.

Comment: "...offering a *reasonable* level of optimization ..."

Comment: The compiler is allowed to optimize as long as the *as-if* rule is adhered to.  This could include the removal of variables (or conversion to constants), as well as the dropping of unused functions.

Comment: I see. My main problem is that the current line skips around, and in and out of different functions in a way I do not expect/understand. Would it be best for me then, to use the `-O0` option? Or is there a good way of making sense of the behavior and stick with `-Og`?

Comment: Either use -O0 or just get used to it

Comment: @ShmilTheCat: "...enables optimizations that *do not interfere* with debugging..."

Comment: Maybe it should be renamed -O0.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal behaviour when compiling with the `-Og` option. At this optimisation level the compiler is allowed to optimize as long as it adheres to the [*as-if* rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). This could include the removal of variables (or conversion to constants), as well as the dropping of unused functions.

The recommendation is either to get used to the skipping or to compile with the `-O0`option.

Comment: That behavior seems in direct contradiction to the claim in the documentation that `-Og` enables "optimizations that do not interfere with debugging". Seeing the values of variables is a pretty component of debugging.

Comment: Doesn't the as-if rule apply to any level of optimization?  It's directly from the standard and doesn't pertain to -Og.  As far as I can tell the -Og flag is totally broken.  It interferes massively with debugging.