# Error: operand out of range (64 is not between 0 and 31)

Tags: c++, gcc, inline-assembly, powerpc, altivec

I'm suffering GCC inline assembly on PowerPC. The program compiles fine with `-g2 -O3`, but fails to compile with `-g3 -O0`. The problem is, I need to observe it under the debugger so I need symbols without optimizations.

Here is the program:

```
$ cat test.cxx
#include <altivec.h>
#undef vector

typedef __vector unsigned char uint8x16_p;

uint8x16_p VectorFastLoad8(const void* p)
{
  long offset = 0;
  uint8x16_p res;
  __asm(" lxvd2x  %x0, %1, %2    \n\t"
        : "=wa" (res)
        : "g" (p), "g" (offset/4), "Z" (*(const char (*)[16]) p));
  return res;
}
```

And here's the error. (The error has existed since [PowerPC vec_xl_be replacement using inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49215090/608639), but I have been able to ignore it until now).

```
$ g++ -g3 -O0 -mcpu=power8 test.cxx -c
/home/test/tmp/ccWvBTN4.s: Assembler messages:
/home/test/tmp/ccWvBTN4.s:31: Error: operand out of range (64 is not between 0 and 31)
/home/test/tmp/ccWvBTN4.s:31: Error: syntax error; found `(', expected `,'
/home/test/tmp/ccWvBTN4.s:31: Error: junk at end of line: `(31),32(31)'
```

I believe this is the sore spot from the *.s listing:

```asm
#APP
 # 12 "test.cxx" 1
         lxvd2x  0, 64(31), 32(31)
```

There's some similar issues reported when using `lwz`, but I have not found one discussing problems with `lxvd2x`.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

---

Here's the head of the `*.s` file:

```asm
$ head -n 40 test.s
        .file   "test.cxx"
        .abiversion 2
        .section        ".toc","aw"
        .align 3
        .section        ".text"
        .machine power8
.Ltext0:
        .align 2
        .globl _Z15VectorFastLoad8PKv
        .type   _Z15VectorFastLoad8PKv, @function
_Z15VectorFastLoad8PKv:
.LFB0:
        .file 1 "test.cxx"
        .loc 1 7 0
        .cfi_startproc
        std 31,-8(1)
        stdu 1,-96(1)
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 96
        .cfi_offset 31, -8
        mr 31,1
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 31
        std 3,64(31)
.LBB2:
        .loc 1 8 0
        li 9,0
        std 9,32(31)
        .loc 1 12 0
        ld 9,64(31)
#APP
 # 12 "test.cxx" 1
         lxvd2x  0, 64(31), 32(31)

 # 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
        xxpermdi 0,0,0,2
        li 9,48
        stxvd2x 0,31,9
        .loc 1 13 0
        li 9,48
        lxvd2x 0,31,9
```

---

Here's the code generated at `-O3`:

```
$ g++ -g3 -O3 -mcpu=power8 test.cxx -save-temps -c
$ objdump --disassemble test.o | c++filt

test.o:     file format elf64-powerpcle

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <VectorFastLoad8(void const*)>:
   0:   99 06 43 7c     lxvd2x  vs34,r3,r0
   4:   20 00 80 4e     blr
   8:   00 00 00 00     .long 0x0
   c:   00 09 00 00     .long 0x900
  10:   00 00 00 00     .long 0x0
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... How is this question lacking a MCVE? I've got the problem isolated to a single function with 3 lines demonstrating the error.

Comment: It is certainly not lacking MCVE. It is just some people have troubles understanding the question, so they decided to express this inability as a downvote/VTC.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyA. The more I think about it, it is probably one of those bot scripts using a puppet account running against my account.

Comment: What asm gets generated with `-O3 -S` for the `lxvd2x` line ?

Comment: @PaulR - `lxvd2x  34, 3, 0` is listed in the `*.s` file. `objdump` says `lxvd2x  vs34,r3,r0` is the object file. Added to the question.

Comment: you can use `-Og` to keep symbols for debuggin while still have some optimizations turned on

Comment: Doesn't gcc have builtins for this?  I see `LXVD2X` mentioned [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/PowerPC-AltiVec_002fVSX-Built-in-Functions.html).

Comment: @David - Yes, but the problem is, the compilers load a vector which is endian-reversed on LE machines. Then, two more instructions are used after the load to reverse the vsx register. I have no idea why the compilers don't reverse the vector elements at compile time and just load the register with one instruction at runtime.

Comment: @David - The net effect is, I've got BLAKE2B running at 3.54 cycles per byte (cpb) on big-endian systems; but it runs at 8.1 to 8.4 cpb on little-endian systems. BLAKE2B requires 65 loads, so I'm burning 3x65 insns for each execution of the compression function instead of 1x65.

Comment: Sigh, It's always something.  I assume you've already looked at the powerpc [constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html)?  It talks about using  ‘m’ or ‘es’ instead of Z.  Not sure how that could help, but it might be worth a shot.  I assume you've already experimented with some of the other constraints instead of `g`?

Comment: @phuclv: `-Og` is separate from `-g`, isn't it?   I thought`-Og` is just an optimization level that was supposed to be good for edit/compile/run cycles, but without the `-O0` behaviour of making every variable effectively `volatile` for fully consistent debugging, so things can stay in registers.  So basically a variant of `-O1`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I though that `-Og` prevents variables from being optimized out as I've read somewhere. Looks like that's not the case [Variables optimized out with g++ and the -Og option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31435771/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the generated asm has register+offset operands for RA and RB, but  the `lxvd2x` instruction only takes direct register addresses (ie, no offsets).

It looks like you've got your constraints wrong there. Looking at the inline asm:

```
__asm(" lxvd2x  %x0, %1, %2    \n\t"
    : "=wa" (res)
    : "g" (p), "g" (offset/4), "Z" (*(const char (*)[16]) p));
```

Firstly, you have one output operand and three input operands (so four in total), but only three operands used in your template.

I'm assuming that your function reads directly from `*p`, and it doesn't clobber anything, so it looks like this is an unused operand for indicating a potential memory access (more on that below). We'll keep it simple for now; dropping it gives us:

```
__asm(" lxvd2x  %x0, %1, %2    \n\t"
    : "=wa" (res)
    : "g" (p), "g" (offset/4));
```

Compiling that, I still get an offset used for the RA and/or RB:

```
 lxvd2x  0, 40(31), 9
```

Looking at the docs for the `"g"` constraint, we see:

> 'g':
>
> Any register, memory or immediate integer operand is allowed,
>     except for registers that are not general registers.

However, we can't provide a memory operand here; only a register (without offset) is allowed. If we change the constraint to `"r"`:

```
 __asm(" lxvd2x  %x0, %1, %2    \n\t"
       : "=wa" (res)
       : "r" (p), "r" (offset/4));
```

For me, this compiles to a valid `lxvd2x` invocation:

```
 lxvd2x  0, 9, 10
```

- which the assembler happily accepts.

Now, as @PeterCordes has commented, this example no longer indicates that it may access memory, so we should restore that memory input dependency, giving:

```
 __asm(" lxvd2x  %x0, %1, %2    \n\t"
    : "=wa" (res)
    : "r" (p), "r" (offset/4), "m" (*(const char (*)[16]) p));
```

In effect, all we've done is alter the constraints from `"g"` to `"r"`, forcing the compiler to use non-offset register operands.

Comment: Beware that asking for pointers in registers does *not* imply that the pointed-to memory is also an input.  Dead-store elimination and/or reordering of stores across the asm statement can break your code.  So you either need a `"memory"` clobber (slow) or a dummy `"m"` operand that's unused by the asm template (except maybe in a comment so you can see what you got).  This was a problem with the original code, too, I guess, but definitely worth mentioning here.

Comment: @PeterCordes yep, good point; that's likely what the initial (third) output operand was for.

Comment: Oh, yes, the `"Z" (*(const char (*)[16]) p))` *input* operand will do the trick nicely, assuming `"Z"` is something like `"m"`.  I hadn't looked at the question, but it's fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the feedback, I've edited the answer to suit.

Comment: That you very much. I found `"r"` worked too through fiddling, but I did not want to diverge from what I was told to use several months ago because I don't understand the Rube Goldberg machine very well. The tool is a complete mess to me. (I'd love to see them design a car, and see how screwed up they can make starting, steering and stopping. I would be amused for years).

Comment: I also found `"m" (*(const char (*)[16])` makes a mess of the code. Performance drops by 3x. I no longer use it. The inline assembler is responsible for understanding what I write. If they can't get it right then they need to get the hell out of the way until they fix their broken tool.

Comment: It may increase performance, but possibly at the cost of correctness; the compiler needs to know that the (opaque-to-the-compiler) inline asm accesses memory at [p,p+16], otherwise it is free to reorder operations around that asm. The assembler isn't aware of those dependencies, and can't do that itself - it's just turning the generated asm into binary instructions.