# How to walk through Python opcode while debugging cpython?

Tags: python, c, gdb, cpython

I want to understand the functioning of Python Interpreter. I understand the process of generation on opcode and want to better understand the interpreter part. For that I read a lot on internet and got to know about `for (;;)` loop in `ceval.c` file in python interpreter(Cpython).

Now I want to interpret the following python code `a.py`:

```
a = 4
b = 5
c = a + b
```

when i do `python -m dis a.py`

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (4)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a)

  2           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)

  3           8 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             10 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             12 BINARY_ADD
             14 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now I have put the debug point in `switch(opcode)` line in `ceval.c`. And now when i start the debugger it comes to this position for more than 2000 times. I think this is because before starting, python has to do some other interpretations stuff as well. So, my question is how do I debug only the relevant opcodes instructions?

Basically, how do i know the instruction I am debugging are actually from the program I created?

Please help me out with the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do a lot of **CPython** debugging  for better understanding the way it works. The lack of possibility to set a **gdb** breakpoint in **Python** source files I solved by writing a **C** extension module.

**The idea**: **CPython** is a big program written in **C** language. We can easy debug it as any **C** program - no problems here. If we want to stop execution when the `_PyType_Lookup` function is started, we just run a `break _PyType_Lookup` command. Thus, if we add our own **C** function into the **CPython** program, for example `cbreakpoint`, we can stop execution every time the `cbreakpoint` is called. And if we will find the way to insert this `cbreakpoint` function into the `source.py`, we will get the required functionality - every time the interpreter will see the `cbreakpoint`, it will be stopped (if we set `break cbreakpoint` before). We can do that by writing a **C** extension".

How I did that (I can miss something, because I am reproducing from memory):

1. Downloaded a **CPython** source into the `~/learning_python/cpython-master` directory and compiled it. There were some intricacies - [Can't get rid of “value has been optimized out” in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56824992/2913477).
2. Created a module itself - `my_breakpoint.c`.
3. Created a setup file - `my_breakpoint_setup.py`.
4. Run a

   ```
   ~/learning_python/cpython-master/python my_breakpoint_setup.py build
   ```

   command. It created a `my_breakpoint.cpython-38dm-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` file.
5. Copied the shared object file from previous step into **CPython's** `Lib` directory:

   ```
   cp -iv my_breakpoint.cpython-38dm-x86_64-linux-gnu.so ~/learning_python/cpython-master/Lib/
   ```

   The copying is needed for convenience, otherwise we should have this `.so` file in any directory we want use (import) this module.
6. Now, we can make a following `source.py`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python3

   from my_breakpoint import cbreakpoint

   cbreakpoint(1)
   a = 4

   cbreakpoint(2)
   b = 5

   cbreakpoint(3)
   c = a + b
   ```

   To execute this file we must use our `~/learning_python/cpython-master` interpreter, not a system's `python3`, because the system's python doesn't have the `my_breakpoint` module:

   ```
   ~/learning_python/cpython-master/python source.py
   ```
7. To debug this file do:

   ```
   gdb --args ~/learning_python/cpython-master/python -B source.py
   ```

   Then, inside `gdb`:

   ```
   (gdb) start

   (gdb) break cbreakpoint
   Function "cbreakpoint" not defined.
   Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
   Breakpoint 2 (cbreakpoint) pending.

   (gdb) cont
   ```

   There is one problem. When you are pressing `cont`, `gdb` is stopped at the beginning of the `cbreakpoint` function and you are needing to do many `next` commands to skip this function and a **CPython** function calling code to achieve the beginning of the desired Python code execution. Or you can set a new breakpoint after `cbreakpoint` was hitted, like:

   ```
   (gdb) break ceval.c:1080 ### The LOAD_CONST case beginning
   (gdb) cont
   ```

   But, after doing this many times I were automating these actions, so you can just add these lines into your **~/.gdbinit**:

   ```
   set breakpoint pending on
   break cbreakpoint
       command $bpnum
       tbreak ceval.c:1098
           command $bpnum
           n
           end
       cont
       end
   set breakpoint pending off
   ```

   Now, you just start **gdb** as in the 7 step and do:

   ```
   (gdb) start
   (gdb) cont
   ```

   and you will jumped to the beginning of the `source.py` code execution.

**my_breakpoint.c**

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* cbreakpoint(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    int breakpoint_id;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &breakpoint_id))
        return NULL;

    return Py_BuildValue("i", breakpoint_id);
}

static PyMethodDef my_methods[] = { 
    {"cbreakpoint", cbreakpoint, METH_VARARGS, "breakpoint function"},  
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef my_breakpoint = { 
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,  
    "my_breakpoint",
    "the module for setting C breakpoint in the Python source",
    -1, 
    my_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_my_breakpoint(void){
    return PyModule_Create(&my_breakpoint);
}
```

**my_breakpoint_setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module = Extension('my_breakpoint', sources = ['my_breakpoint.c'])

setup (name = 'PackageName',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'This is a package for my_breakpoint module',
       ext_modules = [module])
```

#### P.S.

I asked the same question in the past, it can be useful for you: [The optimal way to set a breakpoint in the Python source code while debugging CPython by GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57278643/2913477).

Comment: after I got to the `cbreakpoint` I found that `finish` command also got me out of the c extension's function